# gnuplot graphs disappear after zoom

Tags: gnuplot

I run gnuplot with the following command

```
plot for [i=1:2] "+" using (10*$1):($1**i) with lines
```

Two graphs appear. If I then zoom in both graphs suddenly disappear (at a certain zoom level). This is annoying.

Of course, I do not zoom into an empty region ;-)

Does someone know how to fix that?

PS: I use the standard output terminal under linux.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/28149773/2604213 help?

Comment: No, it does not help. Also increasing the sample points with `set samples 1000` does not help.

Comment: hey! have you figured out the answer to this question?

Comment: I use the latex terminal to avoid this problem: set terminal epslatex color standalone ',14'